# Matplotlib Substitute User Input Variables in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to write a program in python that will accept user input to set the colors of a donut pie chart in matplotlib.
Here is what I have that is currently working:

```
#3 ring 3 - Factors
mypie4, _ =ax.pie(factor_size, radius=5-1.4, colors=[a(0.85), a(0.85), 
                                                     g(0.0), a(0.85), 
                                                     g(0.0), 
                                                     b(0.7), b(0.7), b(0.7),
                                                     c(0.85), c(0.85), 
                                                     c(0.85), c(0.85), 
                                                     g(0.0), g(0.0),
                                                     d(0.85), d(0.85), 
                                                     g(0.0)])
plt.setp(mypie4, width=.2, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)
```

Here is what I want to happen:

```
## Show menu ##
print (30 * '-')
print ("   Color Choices for First Quadrant")
print (30 * '-')
print ("1. Blue")
print ("2. Orange")
print ("3. Green")
print ("4. Purple")
print (30 * '-')

## Get input ###
choice = raw_input('Enter your choice [1-4] : ')

### Convert string to int type ##
choice = int(choice)

### Take action as per selected menu-option ###
if choice == 1:
    user_color = [plt.cm.Blues(0.75)]
elif choice == 2:
    user_color = [plt.cm.Oranges(0.75)]
elif choice == 3:
    user_color = [plt.cm.Greens(0.75)]
elif choice == 4:
    user_color = [plt.cm.Purples(0.75)]
else:    ## default ##
    print ("Invalid number. Try again...")    


#3 ring 3 - Factors
mypie4, _ =ax.pie(factor_size, radius=5-1.4, colors=[[user_color], 
                                                     [user_color], 
                                                    [user_color], 
                                                     [user_color], 
                                                     [user_color], 
                                                     b(0.7), b(0.7), b(0.7),
                                                     c(0.85), c(0.85), 
                                                     c(0.85), c(0.85), 
                                                     g(0.0), g(0.0),
                                                     d(0.85), d(0.85), 
                                                     g(0.0)])
plt.setp(mypie4, width=.2, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)
```

I don't know how to call the variable in to the colors property for ax.pie. Using this format, I can do the same for the other quadrants. Attached is the final picture of what I'm producing manually. I'd like to be able to produce these colors automatically.[donut color quadrant wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OBZ3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the colors into a single array. You generated multiple arrays with one value for each.

First you need to save the user input for all quadrants into a single array. Therefore you can use following function:

```
def getQuadrantColor(colorList, quadrantName):
    print (30 * '-')
    print ("   Color Choices for {} Quadrant".format(quadrantName))
    print (30 * '-')
    print ("1. Blue")
    print ("2. Orange")
    print ("3. Green")
    print ("4. Purple")
    print (30 * '-')
    ## Get input ###
    choice = raw_input('Enter your choice [1-4] : ')

    ### Convert string to int type ##
    choice = int(choice)

    ### Take action as per selected menu-option ###
    if choice == 1:
        colorList.append(plt.cm.Blues(0.75))
    elif choice == 2:
        colorList.append(plt.cm.Oranges(0.75))
    elif choice == 3:
        colorList.append(plt.cm.Greens(0.75))
    elif choice == 4:
        colorList.append(plt.cm.Purples(0.75))
    else:    ## default ##
        print ("Invalid number. Try again...") 
        getQuadrantColor(colorList, quadrantName)
```

You can now use this function like

```
colorList = []
quadrants = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
for quadrant in quadrants:
    getQuadrantColor(colorList, quadrant)
```

Now you got all color information and can create the pie chart

```
mypie4, _ =ax.pie(factor_size, radius=5-1.4, colors=colorList)
plt.setp(mypie4, width=.2, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and post results back here.